# Improper Integrals Type 1

Tags: calculus, solution-verification

Prove that if $$\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}f(t)dt$$converges then it is equal to $$\lim_{c \to \infty}\int^c_{-c}f(t)dt.$$
$$$$As we know that $$\begin{aligned}\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}f(t)dt&=\int^a_{-\infty}f(t)dt+\int_a^{\infty}f(t)dt\\&=\lim_{c \to \infty}\int^a_{-c}f(t)dt+\lim_{d \to \infty}\int_a^df(t)dt\end{aligned}$$ and as it is given that $\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}f(t)dt$ converges, so both the limits on the RHS of the above equation exists. Now as $$\lim_{d \to \infty}\int_a^df(t)dt$$ exists so it is equal to $$\lim_{c \to \infty}\int_a^cf(t)dt$$ and hence we get $$\begin{aligned}\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}f(t)dt&=\int^a_{-\infty}f(t)dt+\int_a^{\infty}f(t)dt\\&=\lim_{c \to \infty}\int_{-c}^af(t)dt+\lim_{c \to \infty}\int_a^cf(t)dt\\&=\lim_{c \to \infty}\int_{-c}^cf(t)dt\end{aligned}.$$
$$$$Is My Proof Correct??

Comment: Your proof seems correct.

Answer (score 1):

The value of $\lim_{c \to \infty}\int^c_{-c}f(t)\,dt$ (when it exists) is called the [Cauchy principle value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value). I would instead write your proof as follows:

Assume that $\int_{-\infty}^b f(t)\,dt$ and $\int_b^\infty f(t)\,dt$ exist.
Then $$I=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t)\,dt = \lim\limits_{a \to -\infty} \int_a^b f(t)\,dt + \lim\limits_{c \to \infty} \int_b^c f(t)\,dt = \lim\limits_{c \to \infty} \int_{-c}^b f(t)\,dt + \lim\limits_{c \to \infty} \int_b^c f(t)\,dt.$$

As the two limits exist, we can combine them to get

$$I=\lim\limits_{c \to \infty} \left(\int_{-c}^b f(t)\,dt + \int_b^c f(t)\,dt \right)
=\lim\limits_{c \to \infty} \int_{-c}^c f(t)\,dt,$$

which is the same as the Cauchy principle value. The Cauchy principle value and improper integral are only the same when the integral converges.

As an example, consider $\int_{-\infty}^\infty t\,dt$. Observe that $\int_0^\infty t\,dt$ diverges to $\infty$ and $\int_{-\infty}^0 t\,dt$ diverges to $-\infty$. Therefore, the integral diverges from either side. However, $$\lim\limits_{c \to \infty} \int_{-c}^c t\,dt = \lim\limits_{c \to\infty} \left(\frac{c^2}{2} - \frac{(-c)^2}{2}\right) =  0.$$

Thus the principal value of $\int_{-\infty}^\infty t\,dt$ is zero while the integral itself diverges. They will be the same if and only if the integral converges.

Answer (score 0):

No!
$$\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}f(t)dt=\lim_{c \to \infty}\int^{-c}_{-\infty}f(t)dt+\lim_{c \to \infty}\int^{+c}_{-c}f(t)dt+\lim_{c \to \infty}\int^{+\infty}_{+c}f(t)dt\tag{1}$$
You used $$\lim_{c \to \infty}\int^{+\infty}_{+c}f(t)dt=\lim_{c \to \infty}\int^{-c}_{-\infty}f(t)dt=0$$
which is what is to be proven by the logic of convergence.
After using the above, you play with the middle term of $(1)$ anyhow, but the proof is left way behind.

Comment: No I have only used the fact that if $\lim_{x \to c}f(x)=L$ then $\lim_{y \to c }f(y)=L$

Comment: A variable-change doesn't matter!

Comment: I am not using the fact which you used in your answer I am just using the fact that change in variable doesn't change the limit

Comment: I didn't use anything you have written in your answer, I just used the definition and the above fact of Limits then where is my proof wrong??

Comment: How did you replace the infinities with the limits!

Comment: By the definition

Comment: Which definition? And if such a definition exists, there is nothing to prove for the proof is just the definition you are talking about!

Comment: The definition is $\int_a^{\infty}f(t)dt=\lim_{x \to \infty}\int_a^xf(t)dt$

Comment: **I think** this holds only when the stuff whose limit is being taken converges. If you examine a rapidly fluctuating function like $\sin(\frac1x)$, $$\int_0^{+\infty}\sin(1/x)\neq\lim_{c\to 0^+}\int_c^{+\infty}\sin(1/x)$$

Comment: This integral you are talking about is the Improper integral of both type 1 and type 2 but I am talking only about type 1

Comment: I don't know any type for now. The point is that if the function doesn't converge at $+\infty$, neither would the area underneath it. From $\sin(\frac1x)$, I wanted to point out that going exactly to $0$ and just tending to it can be very different for some weird functions(the same goes for $+\infty$). Takeaway: Avoid $\lim$ for such scoundrel of a function.

Comment: Your definitions are wrong Sameer Baheti, it make no sense to define a integral on an infinite domain by using other integrals on an infinite domain. The definitions of the OP are the classical one to define such integrals.

Comment: I might be wrong about this($\lim$ must mean going till the very end). But could you explain to me why we need to split the integral $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(t)dt$ to put $\lim_{c\to\infty}$? Can't one put the $\lim_{c\to\infty}$ on both upper and lower limit without splitting the integral and  prove it in one step? Thanks in advance!